# Extract URLs from a large file

Tags: sed, grep

I've seen a lot of answers on here but they're (mostly) about HTML files, in my case, i don't have an HTML file, just a 2GB file including random data and URLs which i want to extract, however the URLs are sometimes mixed with random data/text which i don't want in the output

here's a sample:

```
https://example.com/";}i:41067;a:10:{s:3
```

Comment: Where is this random data located? Is it **always** at the end of the line, or can it be elsewhere as well?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae, it can be anywhere in the line

Comment: How would one know where the URL ends? In the example above, does it end just before `"`? Is there always a `"` character at the end of the URL? If not, how would one tell a path apart from "random data"?

Comment: @Kusalananda not sure, they sometimes end with the following -- `]`, `"`, `/`. Obviously all urls start with `http://` or `https://`

Comment: The trick here is to find how the various URLs in your file end, otherwise any solution is just a guess. Can you look into the file and idientify these characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/7109208/1745001 the valid characters in a URL are:

> A-Z, a-z, 0-9, -, ., _, ~, :, /, ?, #, [, ], @, !, $, &, ', (, ), *,
> +, ,, ;, %, and =

so if we assume that's true then you could try:

```
grep -o -E "https?://[][[:alnum:]._~:/?#@!$&'()*+,;%=-]+" file
```

It still may not be 100% accurate since some of those chars can exist only in specific contexts but it's probably the best you can do with a simple grep/regexp.

If your grep supports it, for a bit of extra constraint add a word boundary (e.g. `\<` in GNU grep) before the `http` too.

Answer (score 1):

Read `man grep` and do something like

```
grep -o -E 'https?://[^"]+' the_file
```

Comment: well i've tried that, but i still get random data such as html tags, newlines, markdown, etc

Comment: The script posted will work for the sample input you provided which is all we have to go on when trying to help you solve your problem. If you have other input that this doesn't work fro then include those cases in the sample input (and so far missing expected output) in your question. Also - it is not possible for the posted script to produce output that includes newlines so maybe you did something wrong when you ran it?

Comment: @EdMorton sorry for the inconvenience, the file is quite critical so i couldn't really provide a larger sample. however, when i said it contains newlines i was talking about `\n`

Comment: Thanks! This with "find" to search all files and output to a file did amazing job. I was able to extract the filenames and the URLs in a single line from all files.
`find . -iname '*' | xargs grep -o -E 'https?://[^"]+' > output_file.txt`